# Ошибка отправки данных через WinSock

Tags: c, winsock, сокет

Это опять я :) 
Есть такая функция:

```
char* HtmlList(char html[])
{
    char                headers[255];
    char                Content_Length[1024];
    char                result[1024];

    sprintf(Content_Length, "Content-Length: %d\r\n", (char) strlen(html));
    strcpy(headers, "HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n");
    strcat(headers, "Content-Type: text/html\r\n");
    strcat(headers, Content_Length); 
    strcat(headers, "Connection: close\r\n\r\n");
    strcat(headers, html);
    strcpy(result, headers);

    return result;
}
```

Ну и пытаюсь ее вызвать:

```
void Main_WebServer()
{
    SOCKET              Winsock;
    char                Buf[255];
    //char*             buffer;
    char                Content_Length[1024];
    char                headers[255];
    struct sockaddr_in client; 
    int clientsize = sizeof(client); 
    int s;

    char html[] = "<b>TEST!</b>";
    *Buf = (char) HtmlList(html);

    Winsock = Start_Server(5656);
    listen(Winsock, 5);

    while (1)
    {
        s = accept(Winsock, (struct sockaddr*)&client, &clientsize);
        if (s == INVALID_SOCKET) break;

        send(s, Buf, (int)strlen(Buf), 0);
    }

    closesocket(Winsock);  // закрытие сокета 
    WSACleanup(); 
}
```

Компилируется без ошибок, но не работает. Вместо `<b>TEST!</b>` какие-то символы, при подключении через `netcat`.

Но если вынести всё в одну функцию, то работает.

Comment: sprintf(Content_Length, "Content-Length: %d\r\n", (char) strlen(html));
    

**strlen() к char приводить нельзя** обрежет, результат может стать отрицатеьным.

Comment: Сразу не заметил:

    char                result[1024];
    ...
    return result;

Серьезная ошибка. Нельзя возвращать адрес переменной **в стеке** (автоматической).

Проще всего в Вашем случае сделать int HtmlList(char html[], char *result_buf) в  result_buf она и разместит результат, а вернет его длину (как раз для send()).

Answer (score 1):

А что функция выдает отдельно, без подключений.
Насколько понимаю, дело тут в области видимости переменных.
result перестает существовать, как только выходим из функции.
И еще один момент - зачем выделять память под массив символов для Buf, если затем использовать его в качестве указателя?

Comment: дак я учусь )

Comment: Я так и понял. Все тут учаться. =)
Можно передавать указатель на массив и его длину в качестве параметра функции, как уже сделано с html.
http://www.cyberguru.ru/programming/cpp/cpp-language-straustrup2-page4.html -- вот здесь можно посмотреть, что я имел ввиду.